# Upgrade AngularJS stack from 1.3 to 1.5

Tags: angularjs, npm

[image]Currently I am working on an project that uses AngularJS 1.3.2 along with that it also includes Angular-sanitize, angular-touch, angular-resource, angular-mocks, angular-ui, and angular-spinner. These all are in version 1.3.2 and I need all these library to 1.5.0. After googling for few minutes I found `upgrade-angularjs [argument][version]` command to upgrade the full stack [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/upgrade-angular). But its not working for me and I keep getting the above error. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: When you post a question be sure to post exactly what you tried, what happened, and what errors, if any that you got. Just saying "it didn't work" makes it pretty hard to troubleshoot

Comment: Added the error screenshot

Comment: Probably annoying but I would recommend moving from 1.3 to 1.4 then 1.5.  We moved from 1.3 to 1.5 a few years ago, but it is a pain to chase fires for devs and qa.  If you make smaller moves it is easier to keep track of migration changes like you see in the docs.  https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration#migrating-from-1-3-to-1-4

Comment: @Winnemucca Did you just use npm to upgrade or manually replaced the files?